# Visual Studio 2017 Libcurl unresolved external symbol __imp_ префикс

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lib

Здравствуйте решил написать не большой код на libcurl, но вот в чем причина мне вожна работоспособность данной программы на любых компьютерах поэтому я использую статические библиотеки, но вот в чем проблема при попытки компилирования программы она выбивает ошибки на примере

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets
```

Причем похожих ошибок 47, но когда я использую динамические библеотеки, то все компилируется и работает, но это только на моем компьютере.

Устанавливал libcurl по вот этому мануалу:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Код для компиляции библиотек:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17
```

Comment: Похоже, вы подсовываете статические библиотеки, но компилируете с ключом /Md - ну, т.е. вызываете функции динамические. libcurl скомпилирован как? с вызовами статических или динамических библиотек?

Comment: Ну мне и нужны статические библиотееи не так ли? Вот название папки с библеотеками libcurl-vc17-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl вроде это статические библиотеки компилировал так: nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17. Вроде все верно.

Comment: Я просто вижу, что у вас в ваших файлах - вызовы функций из DLL. Значит, что-то у вас скомпилировано именно так, для работы с DLL. А библиотеки подсунуты статические. Вот и нестыковка. Ошибка указывает на какой файл? Из libcurl иди вашего "небольшого кода"?

Comment: Ошибка указывает на libcurl_a.lib. Без использования libcurl библиотек все нормально компилируется со статическими библиотеками. В настройка проэкта стоит параметр Multi-thread /MT.

Comment: Похоже, эта библиотека скомпилирована с использованием динамического рантайма... Надо смотреть все ключики компиляции в файлах.

Comment: Можно про это по подробнее никогда не работал с libcurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При компилировании curl кроме ключа mode, который определяет получится ли библиотека статической или динамической, есть еще и ключ RTLIBCFG, который определяет какой рантайм будет использован.

Пример команды:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17 WITH_SSL=static ENABLE_IDN=no ENABLE_WINSSL=no ENABLE_SSPI=no MACHINE=x86 DEBUG=no RTLIBCFG=static
```

В данном случае курл еще и с опенссл компилируется, но линковаться будет статически уже в самой аппликации и эти файлы должны быть доступны в подкаталоге deps.

Более детальную информацию можно посмотреть в файле `winbuild\BUILD.WINDOWS.txt`